WLAN connects fine, but AP = default gateway is unreachable
On my Laptop I can reliably connect to my WLAN. The connection is stable. I get an IP address by the DHCP on the Access Point (AP). Everything looks fine, but there is no route to the IP of the AP itself, which is my default gateway and first DNS to the internet.

AP IP is 192.168.0.1
My IP is 192.168.0.178
IP Mask is 255.255.255.0

"ping 127.0.0.1" is OK
"ping 192.168.0.1" yields "host unreachable"
"mtr 192.168.0.1" yields "no route to host"
"ip addr" yields
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:ce:62:3a:50:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:6f:c9:57:7d:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.178/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 86351sec preferred_lft 86351sec
4: enx04bf1b707f1b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:bf:1b:70:7f:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

If I connect with my Android phone (instead of the laptop) to the very same AP, everything is fine, I can surf the internet. Restarting my AP does not change anything. Switching off my WiFi and switching it back on does not change anything. Putting my Laptop to suspend mode and starting it anew does not change anything. Connecting to my phones WLAN bears exactly the same problems as connecting to my APs WLAN. I am able to post this by using USB tethering on my phone.
This state sprung into existence while watching youtube. The video just suddenly stopped loading. It happened before, but I don't know how it fixed itself last time, maybe I did something else offline and when I came back it was all good, I don't remember...
Can it be a hardware problem? But then why can I reliably connect and get an IP from the DHCP on the AP?
I run Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my Laptop.
Edit (Sep 7th, 8:34 CET):
"ip route" yields
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx0224646f080a scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.178 metric 600 

"ip neigh" yields
192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 lladdr 9c:a9:e4:c7:1f:b4 DELAY

(DELAY = state not yet validated) or
192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0  INCOMPLETE

(INCOMPLETE = An ARP request was sent for that address, but there is no reply) or
192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0  FAILED

If I connect to my phones mobile hotspot, it's exactly the same behavior, so the problem must be local to my laptop, not the AP. However, I have no clue what to look for...
Edit (Sep 7th, 11:00 CET):
"systemctl status NetworkManager.service" yields
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-09-04 08:29:36 CEST; 3 days ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1049 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 57592)
     Memory: 11.8M
        CPU: 16.810s
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1049 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8205] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.155
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8247] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8508] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8511] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8514] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8521] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8523] policy: set 'RSE' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8566] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1725699110.8571] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep 07 10:51:50 Schlepptop NetworkManager[1049]: <warn>  [1725699110.8647] dns-sd-resolved[80581503b07c2a92]: send-updates SetLinkDomains@5 failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 5 not known

A new hint? No idea, what it means though... Only thing is, when I run "ip link" there is no link 5. There are only links 1 through 4 (see above) and another one with higher number (15 right now) for my USB tethering as this is virtual and recreated everytime I reconnect it.
Edit (Sep 8th, 16:25 CET):
Just restarted my laptop, now everything is fixed. I did not change any setting. All previously mentioned outputs are the same, except the failed/unreachable etc. states are gone.
I do not want to restart my whole machine everytime that happens. Which subsystem/service/whatever may I have to restart in this case to fix it?

what is the output of ip route

@JaromandaX Thanks for your question. I added the answer and some more information.

An ip neigh status of DELAY is OK, have just seen it on a working system. Try also running systemctl status NetworkManager.service or nmcli monitor to see if the Network Manager is reporting any diagnostic information about the wlp2s0 device changing state.

@ChesterGillon Thanks for your input. I updated the question. Does the output cast some light on my situation?
